# How to open markdown file in arbitrary editor like Visual Studio Code Python

Tags: python, file

I am building a Python script which should open me a markdown file based on a hotkey. I don't want to manipulate anything with python I just wanna start the the md file with an editor like Visual Studio Code.

If I try to call `os.system("pathToMdFile")` or `subprocess.Popen("pathToMdFile")`. I get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '"pathToMdFile"'`.

How can I open the md file?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

`os.system(f"open {"pathToMdFile"}")` or `subprocess.call(('open', "pathToMdFile"))`